# Python defaultdict

Tags: python, lambda, collections, defaultdict

I found something strange that I couldn't understand.
This is the case:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(lambda: len(a))
```

This is just the part of the code, and the code has never defined 'a' above.

The questions are:

- Is it possible to use `defaultdict` as is, not specifying the variable previously?
- If possible, what is the meaning of that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is best explained in an example:

```
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: len(b))
>>> b = 'abcd'
>>> a[0]
4
```

As you can see, it is possible to use `b` in the `lambda` even though the `b` does not yet exist at that point. What is important is that `b` exists at the time when the `lambda` is executed. At that point, Python will look for a variable named `b` and use it.

---

Note also that the original code does not necessarily use length of the defaultdict itself. It simply evaluates whatever `a` is at that point. See this example:

```
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: len(a))
>>> a['a']
0
>>> a['b']
1
```

So far, so good. But then rename some things:

```
>>> x = a
>>> a = []
>>> x['c']
0
>>> x['d']
0
```

Now the deaultdict is named `x`, but it does not use `len(x)`. It still uses `len(a)`. This caveat may become important if you sent the defaultdict to a function where `a` does not mean anything.

Comment: So much thx for your reply.

Anyway, but at 2nd block, why is a['a']=0?

Comment: Because at the point when `a['a']` is evaluated `len(a)` is still `0`. After getting the result of the lambda (`0`), that value is stored in `a['a']`.

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Thank you for your big help :)

Answer (score 1):

you are saying to default dict, when i try to do something with a key and it doesnt exist, use this lambda as the inital value for the key. since your lambda is using a (i.E the dict its self) and you say the length of it. It means when you perform operations using a key thats not in the dict then the dict will use the lambda instead or in this case the length of the dict as the value

```py
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(lambda: len(a))

a['one'] += 5 #here dict length is 0 so value is 0 + 5 = 5
a['two'] += 2 #jere dict length is 1 so value is 1 + 2 = 3
a['three'] += 1 #here dict length is 2 so value is 2 + 1 = 3
print(a.items())
print(a['newval']) #here newval doesnt exist so will use default value which is length of dict I.E 3
```

**OUTPUT**

```
dict_items([('one', 5), ('two', 3), ('three', 3)])
3
```

Comment: "use this lambda as the inital value for the key." better phrased, *call* this function to generate the value for the key

Answer (score 1):

Here's how `defaultdict` works. Say you have a dict of lists and you're setting values for keys that might not exist. In that case you'd do something like this:

```
d = dict()
if some_key not in d:
    d[some_key] = list()
d[some_key].append(some_value)
```

`defaultdict` does this automatically for you by passing it a callable, e.g., `int`, `list`, `set`, which will call `int()` (default value 0), `list()` (default value empty list), and `set()` (default value empty set) respectively. Your lambda is also a callable, which returns integers, so you'll have a dict with int values. But the value you get from the expression will depend on the size of the dict.

Can you do `a = defaultdict(lambda: len(a))`?

Yes, you can. The lambda will not be executed until called which is when it'll look up the name `a`. Compare these two cases.

```
f = lambda: len(a)
a = defaultdict(f)
a[0]                  # this is when the lambda is called for the first time
```

But,

```
g = lambda: len(b)
g()                   # this will raise a NameError
b = defauldict(g)
```